# Speaker input connector

Tags: amplifier, connector, banana-jack

I want to buy connectors which are generally at the input of speakers or amps. I have attached a picture below. [image]

What are these plugs called? I cannot find these on Digikey.
Thank you for your help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this link:
http://www.electricalcableconnectors.com/sale-7620516-terminal-connector-spring-speaker-binding-post-jack-female-for-audio-video.html    They certainly look the same. Otherwise, they may be the very old style - probably not manufactured anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Those are called binding posts.  They will accept banana plugs.  They can also take bare wires or spade lugs under the plastic nuts.

Answer (score 0):

The connector you've posted is similar to a Visaton BT 95/75 [image]